# Setting AVMutableComposition's frameDuration

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

I'm playing with the `AVEditDemo` project, from Apple's `WWDC 2010` sample pack, and I'm trying to change the frame rate of the exported video. The video is exported using an `AVMutableComposition` on which the frameDuration is set like that:

```
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30); // 30 fps
```

For some reason, changing the 30 to 25 does not change the `framerate` of the video exported with the `AVAssetExportSession`. Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the `AVAssetExportSession` preset takes precedence over the `AVVideoComposition` `frameDuration`. I've opened a bug report:

http://openradar.appspot.com/11127156

Comment: Do you know if this has been fixed?

Comment: No news from Apple… :-(

Comment: Have you tested on iOS 8 or OS X Yosemite?

Comment: Nope… If someone did, I would be interested by the answer.

Answer (score 8):

The client can set `sourceTrackIDForFrameTiming` to `kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid` and `frameDuration` to an appropriate value in order to specify the maximum output frame rate independent of the source track timing.

```
videoComposition.sourceTrackIDForFrameTiming = kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid;
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
```

Comment: How did you discover that setting sourceTrackIDForFrameTiming to kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid was an option?

Answer (score 5):

replying MonsieurDart's answer:
I didn't try the `AVEditDemo` but I'm not having this issue on iOS 8, nor did I have it on iOS 7.

I'm using a `AVMutableVideoComposition` and setting it as the `AVAssetExportSession's` videoComposition.

```
.
.
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
AVMutableVideoComposition *compositionInstruction = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
compositionInstruction.instructions = @[instruction];
compositionInstruction.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
.
.    
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.videoComposition = compositionInstruction;
```

where the videoTrack is a `AVMutableCompositionTrack` created from the asset