# AVMutableVideoComposition frameDuration not working

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-encoding, avkit, avvideocomposition

I have a `AVMutableVideoComposition` and I want to set the export frame rate (e.g. 10 fps):

`videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 10);`

I've got various other instructions like transform on the composition and they all work, however, the exported video just ignores this property and exports at the original video's frame rate.

Here is my code:

```
AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoCompositionWithPropertiesOfAsset:asset];
...
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 10);
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *transformInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
instruction.timeRange = videoTrack.timeRange;
[transformInstruction setTransform:matrix atTime:kCMTimeZero];
instruction.layerInstructions = @[ transformInstruction ];
videoComposition.instructions = @[ instruction ];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:exportURL error:nil];
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality];
exportSession.outputURL = exportURL;
exportSession.outputFileType = exportOptions.fileType;
exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition;
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = exportOptions.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    //video is exported with all the settings correctly, except the frame rate.
}];
```

I've also tried `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` instead of `AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality` as the export session preset, but nothing changed.

Why is the `frameDuration` ignored, and how can I make it work **without the use of another 3rd party library such as [SDAVAssetExportSession](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession)**?

I've already seen [Setting AVMutableComposition's frameDuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725193/setting-avmutablecompositions-frameduration) but there's no solution there. However, when I examine the `SDAVAssetExportSession`'s source, it uses the `frameDuration` property just as I am (see https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession/blob/master/SDAVAssetExportSession.m#L308), but for some reason mine is not working. But as that works, there must be a workaround even if there's a bug with Apple's AVKit. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: @RoiMulia nope, I've ended up living with the fact that I can't do it (without changing the whole pipeline infrastructure) and accepted the frame rate as-is. Of course, it is NOT a solution.